# How do I display each content of this array [45,70,65] on a separate row in django

Tags: python, django

How do I display each content of the array `[45,70,65]` on a separate row in Django? Any time I use

```
{% for keep in keep1 %}
    {{ keep }}
{% endfor %}
```

It keeps displaying `40 70 65` on three different rows, *i.e.*

```
40 70 65
40 70 65
40 70 65
```

but what I want is

```
40
70
65
```

Comment: So you are saying you are passing `keep1 = [45,70,65]` in the Context to the template? You should probably also show the view code that renders the template.

Comment: As @alan says, please post the code for your view as well.

Comment: I see you tried to add your view code to my answer (I didn't reject the edit, but other community members correctly did). Please add it to *your question* instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you're outputting to HTML (and I imagine you are), you'll need `<br/>` elements in your template, or a `<pre>` tag:

```
{% for keep in keep1 %}
    {{ keep }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
<pre>
    {% for keep in keep1 %}
    {{ keep }}
    {% endfor %}
</pre>
```

Whitespace characters (spaces, new lines, *etc.*) have [special treatment in HTML](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html), and newlines by themselves are not usually displayed.

As above, I'd still be interested to see your view code, however. It looks like

```
keep1 = [[45,70,65], [45,70,65], [45,70,65]]
```

from your output, which is not what you want. Perhaps a mistake with a list comprehension or something?